# What is the difference between "Copy link address" and "Copy link text"?

Tags: android, mobile, youtube

I haven't yet figured out the difference between "Copy link address" and "Copy link text". Aren't they the same? What is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
<a href="http://example.com">Click here</a>
             ^---link address     ^---link text
```

Comment: Why does that interest the user if both the same?

Comment: because copying the link text ("Click here") and sending that to your buddy saying " you gotta view this video" is utterly useless. "click here" means nothing without the link address. just because the link text CAN be the same as the link address doesn't mean they're ALWAYS the same.

Answer (score 1):

copy link address is like to copy this type of link address http://stackoverflow.com :) 
and copy link text is like to copy this type of text  "Click to go stackoverflow site :)